# django-social-auth Facebook redirect loop

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I've inherited a project, and am trying to make sense of the Facebook authentication.

It's using django-social-auth (0.6.1), and for some reason during Facebook auth, the app enters an endless redirect loop between "/login/facebook/" and "/complete/facebook?code=".

Any help with solving this would be appreciated! I'm not even sure how to got closer to the root of the issue, since I'm new to Django. I am, however, quite experienced with Rails (and thus the general structure of Django, if not the details)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that adding a handler to the "pre_update" signal causes this, as seen here : https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/issues/234

However, I still require a workaround to execute the code that used to run there...